# What does the error message "bad request" mean while creating a azsphere tenant

Tags: azure, bad-request

I am trying to create a azsphere tenant in powershell. After I have logged into azsphere CLI I run the command:

> azsphere tenant create --name MyTenant --force-additional

I confirm and get the error message:

> Command failed due to invalid parameters. Check the values you provided and try again. The Azure Sphere Security Service sent the following message: Bad Request

I have tried to use another tenant name and looked up the problem online without any succes

Edit: When I run the command with --debug and --verbose parameters I get additional information about the error. I will paste all the information here.

```sh
 cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: Request URL: 'https://prod.core.sphere.azure.net/v2/tenants/create'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: Request method: 'POST'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: Request headers:
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Client-SDK': 'azsphere_v2'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Client-SDK-Version': '22.02'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Accept': 'application/json'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Content-Length': '34'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'x-ms-client-request-id': '554eede3-9f9e-11ec-8137-3868938df738'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-sphere-publicapi/0.4.3 Python/3.8.9 (Windows-10-10.0.22000-SP0)'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Authorization': '*****'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: Request body:
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: {"TenantFriendlyName": "MyTenant"}
urllib3.connectionpool: https://prod.core.sphere.azure.net:443 "POST /v2/tenants/create HTTP/1.1" 400 132
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: Response status: 400
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: Response headers:
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Date': 'Wed, 09 Mar 2022 11:44:37 GMT'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Content-Length': '132'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Request-Context': 'appId='
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'api-supported-versions': '2.0'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: Response content:
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: "Exception of type 'Azure.Sphere.Services.PublicApi.Service.Handlers.Implementation.HandlerExceptionWithHttpStatusCode' was thrown."
cli.azure.cli.core.util: azure.cli.core.util.handle_exception is called with an exception:
cli.azure.cli.core.util: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\azsphere-cli\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 691, in _run_job
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\azsphere-cli\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 328, in __call__
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\azsphere-cli\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/command_operation.py", line 121, in handler
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\azsphere-cli\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azext_sphere_cloudmanagement/tenant/custom.py", line 94, in create_tenant
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\azsphere-cli\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azext_sphere_cloudmanagement/tenant/custom.py", line 106, in create_tenant_request
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\azsphere-cli\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/sphere/cli/core/async_wrapper.py", line 73, in wrapped_operation
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\azsphere-cli\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/sphere/publicapi/operations/_tenants_operations.py", line 142, in create
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: Operation returned an invalid status 'Bad Request'
Content: "Exception of type 'Azure.Sphere.Services.PublicApi.Service.Handlers.Implementation.HandlerExceptionWithHttpStatusCode' was thrown."

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\azsphere-cli\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\knack/cli.py", line 231, in invoke
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\azsphere-cli\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 657, in execute
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\azsphere-cli\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 720, in _run_jobs_serially
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\azsphere-cli\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 712, in _run_job
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\azsphere-cli\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azext_sphere_cloudmanagement/_exception_handler.py", line 192, in tenant_create_exception_handler
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\azsphere-cli\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/sphere/cli/core/cloud_exception_handler.py", line 148, in cloud_exception_handler
knack.util.CLIError: Command failed due to invalid parameters. Check the values you provided and try again.
The Azure Sphere Security Service sent the following message: Bad Request

cli.azure.cli.core.azclierror: Command failed due to invalid parameters. Check the values you provided and try again.
The Azure Sphere Security Service sent the following message: Bad Request
az_command_data_logger: Command failed due to invalid parameters. Check the values you provided and try again.
The Azure Sphere Security Service sent the following message: Bad Request
cli.knack.cli: Event: Cli.PostExecute [<function AzCliLogging.deinit_cmd_metadata_logging at 0x03B125C8>, <function CompleterCache.invalidate_cache at 0x043B2610>]
az_command_data_logger: exit code: 1
cli.__main__: Azure Sphere Utility version 22.02.3.34006
cli.__main__: Command ran in 9.497 seconds (init: 1.297, invoke: 8.200)
```

Comment: may I know are you trying to create **az sphere tenant** newly or are you trying to use the old account to create a new tenant

Comment: @SaiSakethGuduru-MT I am new to using azsphere and I'm not sure that I understand what you mean with "trying to create az sphere tenant newly" but I am trying to create my first tenant using the attached device "Azure Sphere Mt3620".

Comment: @TageDanielsson: Have you tried listing the tenants to see if that was possible at all? Perhaps there is already a tenant with that name or some connection issue occurred. "azsphere tenant list"

Comment: If that is the case then probably you can just use    ** azsphere tenant create --name MyTenant **  rather than  **--force--additional** If you already have a tenant and are certain you want another one, use the **--force-additional** parameter.

Comment: @SaiSakethGuduru-MT When I run the command without --force-additional I get the same error. When I run "azsphere tenant list" nothing happens. I supose that means that I have no tenants.

Comment: @TageDanielsson: In general Azure won't take tenant automatically you need to create it  azsphere tenant create --name <tenant-name or tenant-ID> this is the command to create tenant. Replace <tenant-name> with a name that other users can recognize, such as "Contoso Ltd" or "Contoso Dishwasher Division."

Comment: @SaiSakethGuduru-MT I understand that I need to create a tenant using for example "azsphere tenant create --name myTenant" but when I run this comand in windows powershell it asks me if I am sure that I want to create a tenant. When I confirm it gives me the error i listed in the original question.

Comment: Go through this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-sphere/reference/azsphere-tenant?tabs=cliv2beta#download-error-report once

Comment: Please try to run the command with `--debug` and `--verbose` parameters. That should give you more details about the error.

Comment: @GauravMantri I ran the command with the --debug and --verbose parameters and I got a lot more details about the error but I am afraid that I dont really know what any of it means and how I should go about fixing it.

Comment: Please edit your question and include relevant details in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Go to command prompt downloaded with sdk and setup from there

then the
`azsphere tenant create --name MyTenant`

will work. It worked for me

Comment: This answer does not seem to add anything to what the OP has already tried.